# Not too sure what the " | " does to two sets (With Python)

Tags: python, set, operator-keyword

If i have a couple operations such as the following, 
what exactly is the " | " symbol doing to the two..?

```
a1 = {3,5,3,8}
a2 = {90,42}

a3 = a2  |  a1
a4 = a1  |  a2

a3

{8,42,3,4,90}

a4

{8,42,90,3,4}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @Veedrac: no, it's not.. (and if it were, that'd be an answer, not a comment..)

Comment: @DSM Bah, typing before I think. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3):

The | operator takes the union of the two set objects (unordered lists). so for example...

```
l1 = {1,2,3}
l2 = {2,3,4}
l3 = l1 | l2

print l3 #prints {1,2,3,4}
```

Comment: Where is the 4 coming from in either sets though? Also, how does it come up with that exact ordering of the numbers?

Comment: @adsberger --- a set is unordered.  So basically the program does whatever it wants for the order (there's more to it than that, but you should never expect to know what order it will use in advance)

Comment: When i create the lists you have above and union them I get a1 | a2: {8,42,3,90,5} and a2 | a1: {8,42,3,90,5}. Your results seem fishy to me. I'm not sure of the resulting order, but order isn't to be considered when dealing with sets

Comment: Okay, i must of missed typed them in or something, I'm getting your values now too, thank you I understand the use of the operator now

Comment: I'm glad I can help! Please accept answer if you're satisfied

Answer (score 2):

In this case, youve made a1 and a2 sets.  So note that the duplication in a1 is ignored by python.  The '|' returns a set containing everything that is in at least one.   In set theory this is called the "union".

So
    a1 | a2
returns everything that is in at least one of the two.

You should note that for your a1

```
a1 = {3,5,3,8}
print a1
```

gives

```
set([8, 3, 5])
```

The duplicate 3 is just showing up once since this is a set.  Note that the order looks different because a set is unordered.  It doesn't have to give the same order you put in.  It does things according to what makes the background more efficient.